# Writing text (from a variable) into a file and on a new line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def function(score,name):
    sumOfStudent = (name + ' scored ' + str(score))
    f = open('test.txt', 'wb')
    f.write(sumOfStudent)
    f.close()

user_name = input("Please enter yout full name: ")
user_score = int(input("Please enter your score: "))

function(user_score,user_name)

f = open('test.txt')
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

I was writing a simple program in python which allowed the user to enter information and then for that text to be stored in a .txt file. This worked however it would always write to the same line, I was wondering how I would make the `f.write(sumOfStudent)` on a new line every time (sumOfStudent is the variable to hold user input) Thanks!

Comment: end with a newline. `f.write(sumOfStudent + "\n")`

Comment: You are opening the file in `'w'` (over**w**rite) mode, rather than `'a'` (**a**ppend).

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks for the help! Can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks as well, not sure why I was using 'wb' mode!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey what you are doing is not writing to the end of the file you are overwriting everytime    'w' what you need to be doing is appending it to the file by using    'a'

```
f = open('test.txt', 'a')
```

Also to write to a new line you must tell the program thats what you're doing by declaring a new line    "\n"

```
f.write(sumOfStudent + "\n")
```

Comment: Ahh I see the comments above have already fixed your problem :) sorry for my late answer.